# Get the TextView inside a Card

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

I'm creating a list of Cards and I would liked to get the text inside the TextView that the clicked Card has.

In my adapter I have this:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    ImageView productImage;
    TextView productName;
    TextView productPrice;
    TextView productBest;
    TextView productURL;
    ImageView symbol;

    private ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);


        productImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        productName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        productPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        productBest = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productBest);
        productURL = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productURL);
        symbol = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.symbol);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView urlView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_url);
        String url = urlView.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Long Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }


}
```

But in the *onClick()*, the urlView is getting null. I supose the view is from an element and not from the Card. What should I do then?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is that you are using the view parameter to execute the findViewById.

The view parameter is the view who has been clicked, so necessarily it is not the view container.

You already have executed the findViewById, you don't need to do it anymore.

Your corrected code is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String url = productURL.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code .

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    ImageView productImage;
    TextView productName;
    TextView productPrice;
    TextView productBest;
    TextView productURL;
    ImageView symbol;
    // edited here
    TextView urlView;

    private ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);


        productImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        productName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        productPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        productBest = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productBest);
        productURL = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productURL);
        symbol = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
        // edited here ,add findViewById here
        urlView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_url);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // remove findViewById here
        String url = urlView.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Long Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

}
```